# How to get handles of different controls with the same class name ?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I'm trying to access a third party application's "Text Boxes" using delphi programming so I need to find the handle of each "Text Box" using FindWindowEx(...) function .

The problem is , as all text boxes have the same class name with "NO window name"  this function can just give me the first TextBOx handle !

How can I get the rest of text boxes handles while they have no names ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're interested in FindWindowEx(PARENT_WINDOW_HANDLE, GW_HWNDNEXT, NIL, NIL)

Comment: thanks ! but  "GW_HWNDNEXt" gives the next control handle which may not be the next textbox .

Comment: yep, but he needs to build a recursive function that will enumerate all child windows, for example 2 text boxes could be child of a parent window while other text boxes are child of another window, so he will need to "search" with find first, find next...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `EnumChildWindows` to enumerate all child windows of the third party application's window and test the class name of each enumerated window to see if it is the "Text Box" class. Example:

```
function EnumChildren(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
const
  TextBoxClass = 'EDIT'; (?)
var
  ClassName: array[0..259] of Char;
begin
  Result := True;
  GetClassName(hwnd, ClassName, Length(ClassName));
  if ClassName = TextBoxClass then
    TStrings(lParam).Add(IntToHex(hwnd, 8));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  EnumChildWindows(OtherAppWnd, @EnumChildren, UINT_PTR(Memo1.Lines));
end;
```

Comment: thank you so much . with a little change in your code it worked great .

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `FindWindowEx()` effectively, you need to know the structure of the window's UI ahead of time, such as via Spy++, Winspector, or other similar tool.  That way you know how many controls have the same class type, what their parent/child relationship is in regards to each other, etc so you can code `FindWindowEx()` accordingly.  Alternatively, if the target UI makes use of Dialog IDs (the VCL does not, but Microsoft usually does), then you can use `GetDlgItem()` instead to get the handles of the desired controls directly without having to hunt for them in code (again, Spy++ and similar tools can show you what those IDs are so you can code them).

Answer (score 1):

based @Sertac Akyus my Delphi 7 (2002) 32-Bit code for a Windows 10 64-Bit Pro
remote (local Desktop) application:
(Note: I do not know why, but all the codes here on SO with @s dont work !) :

| Win32API | desc. |
|:-------- | ----- |
| GetClassName(winHandle, @s, Length(s)+1); | **this seems not work !** |
| GetClassName(winHandle, PChar(s), Length(s)+1); | **this works !** |

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    winHandle: HWND;
    winTitle : string;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  s: String;

function EnumChildren(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  ClassName: array[0..259] of Char;
begin
  Result := True;
  GetClassName(hwnd, ClassName, Length(ClassName));
  Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToHex(hwnd,8) + ' ' + ClassName);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;

  // ---------------------------------
  // 1. try to find main window hwnd:
  // ---------------------------------
  winHandle := FindWindow('TwinMain', nil);
  if winHandle < 1 then begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add('Error: 1.'); exit; end else
  ListBox1.Items.Add('win: 0x' + IntToHex(winHandle,8));

  // ---------------------------------
  // 2. try to find window title:
  // ---------------------------------
  SetLength(winTitle, GetWindowTextLength(winHandle));
  GetWindowText(winHandle, PChar(winTitle), Length(winTitle)+1);
  if Length(Trim(winTitle)) < 2 then begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add('Error: 2.'); exit; end else
  ListBox1.Items.Add('title: ' + winTitle);

  // ---------------------------------
  // 3. cross check: try to get class:
  // ---------------------------------
  SetLength(s, 100);
  GetClassName(winHandle, PChar(s), Length(s)+1);
  if Length(Trim(s)) < 2 then begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add('Error: 3.'); exit; end else
  ListBox1.Items.Add('class: ' + s);

  EnumChildWindows(winHandle, @EnumChildren, 0);
end;

(* here comes the form1.dfm file: *)
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 192
  Top = 125
  Width = 389
  Height = 328
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 56
    Top = 48
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object ListBox1: TListBox
    Left = 24
    Top = 112
    Width = 305
    Height = 145
    ItemHeight = 13
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

Hope this helps more than many others articles on SO.
ciao, Jens

Comment: Note: @a modarator on SO: please check the mark up options for table's styles. I am not sure, but I have different display settings for it - in writing the answer editor, and mark up, and text preview all seems be work. But when I publish/post the answer I get other style.